# is it possible to use form-based authentication to implement base auth by Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security

It sounds like to mix two authentication mode into one, but I am really interested if is there any way to get rid of the browser pop up window asking for username/password and use a custom form instead.

I am not sure it is possible, it feels like skipping this login page for any authentication and move the pre-authentication to authenticate user request after the login form is submitted, however 'skipping the login page' seems already violate base-auth.

Or a better question is, how to use a form based auth to verify user profile from server by spring?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set "Authorization" header on client-side to avoid Basic-auth popup:

> 1. Username and password are combined into a string "username:password". Note that username cannot contain the ":" character.[9]
> 2. The resulting string is then encoded using the RFC2045-MIME variant of Base64, except not limited to 76 char/line[10]
> 3. The authorization method and a space i.e. "Basic " is then put before the encoded string.
>      [(c) Wiki-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side)

Better approach is to use Spring Security and their form-based authentication [more info](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/guides/html5/form.html)

Comment: Thank you. could you please enlighten me that with above setting how spring can communicate server to pass and verify the registered user in application server?

Comment: Regarding first or second approach? With basic Authorization Spring will get the info from HTTP header and if you use from-based authentication, Spring will parse request params.

Comment: thanks I am trying to implement a approach with both. So that there will be a form page to send the user inputs(username/password) to verify with the information from application server. So i am curious how the application is able to verify that kind of profile back-and-forth to the server.

Comment: Review the link with Spring tutorial and it will work great. Easier will be to switch from Basic Auth to form-based. Basic-Auth is used more often to secure Rest API.